# Is there solutions in Hadoop 2.2 for this situation?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In Hadoop 2.2, we can use the High Availability feature to deal with the namenode's fault. Is there any solutions to deal with the ResourceManager's fault? If the machine which has the ResourceManager's process is shutdown or offline, could any other machine backup the states.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In YARN, when a ResourceManager fails over, all applications will be restarted. For applications like Hadoop MapReduce which implemented recovery, jobs will continue from their last saved progress.

Failover handling of ResourceManager will be implemented in the future.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I usually let the active namenode and the resourcemanager be the same machine, so if the machine is offline, the standby namenode will become active namenode, but the resourcemanager will be also offline. So the nodemanager won't find the resourcemanager, and the mapreduce task will not continue. So really expect the new feature about the high availability of ResourceManager!

Answer (score 1):

Resource Manager HA developing status is tracked here,
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-149.
And work preserving restart is tracked here,
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-556.
Both of them are under development